#  software center crashes all the time

Tags: 12.04, software-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software center not opening](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185117/software-center-not-opening)

Like the title says my software center crashes all the time. This happens as soon as I start it, I have to force close it to shut it down, and it is pretty much unusable as it refreshes the lists constantly even my installed apps.

Dose this happen to every one ?

Can I keep it from refreshing so often (I don't need it to refresh if I'm just browsing, a manual refresh when I need it would be great.)?

And is there a fix for all the crashes (it becomes grayed out for no reason even when starting up)?

Any comments and answers are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to reinstall the Ubuntu Software Center.

To do that, open the Terminal, and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge software-center
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install software-center
```

Hope this works for you!