# Software Center crashes repeatedly

Tags: software-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>    [software center crashes all the time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177116/software-center-crashes-all-the-time)

My Software Center in Ubuntu 12.04 crashes repeatedly and I have to force close it. I have tried reinstalling, but the issue is not resolved. Please help to resolve the same.

Comment: Try running `software-center` from the Terminal and posting any errors in the body of your original question (**edit, *don't* comment!**). We'll be able to help better with that!

Comment: if you need installing things until you solve this you better use synaptic, and to install deb use gdebi. i prefer them to software center anyway